# Writing an ANTLR action "in between" multiplicity

Tags: antlr

I'm working on an ANTLR grammar that looks like...

```
A : B+;
```

...and I'd like to be able to perform an action before and after each instance of B.  For example, I'd like something like...

```
A : A {out("Before");} B {out("After");}
  | {out("Before");} B {out("After");};
```

So that on the input stream `A B B` I would see the output...

```
Before
After
Before
After
```

Of course the second example isn't valid ANTLR syntax because of the left recursive rule.  Is there a way to accomplish what I want with proper ANTLR syntax?

I should also mention that there are other ways of reaching the B rule so simply surrounding the B rule with before and after won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't something like

```
A : ({out("Before");} B {out("After");})+;
```

work?